# Can't login to Ubuntu 17.04 after editing environment variables for java

Tags: boot, login, java, 17.04, login-screen

I installed Java jdk and updated my `etc/environment` to

```
PATH="/use/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="opt/java/jdk-10.0.1"
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"
```

And today when I rebooted , I couldn't login and I'm stuck in a login loop.

When I enter into the shell I couldn't execute `ls` because it said `/bin` is not included in the PATH environment variable.
I added the following line to the end to the end of `~/.bashrc`

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Now when I login into the shell it gives the same error but I can `ls`, `nano`, etc. in the following commands.

I sense that the login loop is also due to this error. Also I added the following line to the top of `/etc/bash_completion`

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games/usr/local/games"
```

but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Are you able to log into the console (`Ctrl+Alt+F3`)?  Which Desktop environment are you trying to log into... which Login Manager are you using?  Try to identify whether it's the login manager, by changing to a different one.

Comment: Yes I'm being able to log into to console that's how I made so many changes

Comment: Trying to login to Ubuntu, although can't login into GNOME aswell

Comment: What is the output of `find ~/ -mount ! -user $(whoami)`?

Comment: It gives `find: unknown predicate ``-userkartikey'`

Comment: With a single `

Comment: What is the output of `whoami`?

Comment: `-userkartikey`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77864/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-kartikeykant18).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the process of your changes, you have run the elevated command `sudo` in your personal space whereas you have lost permission to some of the files needed for your GUI environment.

You can verify this with this command:

```
$ sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) ~/
```

You can resolve it by giving owner to the problem files with:

```
$ sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) ~/
```

You may also have to verify the integrity of your login manager after taking charge via the commands avaible.  You can do this with lightdm with these two commands:

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall lightdm 
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

As per the chat, errors resulting from the latter commands are due to trying to work with a broken repository... running an EOL version of Ubuntu.  This can be resolved by upgrading or downgrading to a supported version.  Choices are:

- 14.04 LTS (downgrade)
- 16.04 LTS (downgrade)
- 17.10     (upgrade)
- 18.04 LTS (upgrade)

Comment: after upgrading to 17.10 I am still stuck in the login I also did reinstall lightdm and reconfigure lightdm , also, now my Ubuntu system is disconnected from the wifi

Comment: @kartikeykant18 Use the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77864/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-kartikeykant18) area for updates on the issue.